# Difference between two probability problems about horses participating in a race

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

*First problem:*
3 horses participate in the race. I bet on horse number 1. Before the race, an omniscient force told me that Horse 3 would not win. Should I change my choice?

*Second problem*
3 horses participate in the race. I bet on horse number 1. In the middle of the race, horse number 3 breaks his leg. I have the opportunity to change my choice, but should I do it?

I understand that in first task the answer is "yes, I should". Because it's kind of Monty Hall problem.
But I don't understand why the second task isn't. In both cases I recieve 100% valid information about horses. And I get these "hints" before race is finished.

So what's the difference? Does it matter when I get these hints, before the race or in the middle? Why?

Comment: the Monty Hall scenario depends entirely on understanding the rules that Monty is following.  In your first scenario, we have no idea what rules (if any) govern the force which is telling you things.  Perhaps it is lying.  Who knows?  In any case, I see no reason to switch in that scenario.

Comment: And, certainly, there is no reason to switch in the second scenario either.

Comment: If we just read the 2 questions, we can answer : If you have bet on horse n°3, change your bet, and in other cases, you can do what you want. In your answer, you suggest that AFTER your bet, based on your bet which was 'horse n°1', someone has chosen horse n°3, and has disqualified this horse. It as not suggested in the 2 questions, it is suggested only in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion

In both the cases the probability of winning of both the horses ( horse1 and horse2 ) are $\frac{1}{2}$ so there is no point in switching.

The main difference between Monty Hall problem and this case is that in Monty Hall problem the door in which car is present is already fixed and cannot be changed, But here horses have equal strength of winning, So winner is not fixed like before.